# Restrict content access only to Logged In users

Tags: php, .htaccess, caching

I have a folder named `cache`. It has sub-folders and files. I need to make `cache` content accessible only when `isset($_SESSION["logged"])`.

I have routed all requests to cache folder via index.php by placing the following `.htaccess` file in cache folder :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

In `index.php` following check is written :

```
<?php session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION["logged"])) {
    die();
} else {
    header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    die;
}
```

But I am geting error ::

```
This web page has a redirect loop

ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

Could you please debug where I am wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why you get this error simply is that you explicitly implemented an endless loop. Your `header()` call redirects back to the same URL originally requested, so the rewriting rule applies again, things start all over again.

Instead you should output the contents of the requested cache file:

```
<?php 
session_start();
$pathToCachedLocation = '/some/path' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if (isset($_SESSION["logged"]) && file_exists($pathToCacheLocation)) {
    readfile($pathToCacheLocation);
}
```

You will still have to add some additional validation and error handling to make sure the request targets a file actually inside the physical cache location (see [`realpath()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php)) and read permission exists (see [`is_readable()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-readable.php)). Also some http headers probably make sense sending. The above example is kept simple to demonstrate the approach.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but `file_get_contents($pathToCacheLocation);` is not working in this case

Comment: @KunwarbirS. Oh, sorry about that. Indeed `file_get_contents()` does not make sense here (though it would be easy to fix that). I changed the example code to use `readfile()` which clearly makes more sense here.